# Where to download MySQLdump.ext newer version than mysqldump.exe ver 5.7.1.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Trying to dump simple database via MySQL Workbench by clicking...
Server > Data Export >mydb>Start Export

Get Message: mysqldump Version Mismatch... the message shows these versions
mysqldump.exe ver 5.7.1.7
MySQL Server ver 5.7.19

Read most of the post on topic here and see I need to point Workbench to newer version of mysqldump.exe via clicking Edit > Preferences > Administration

But when I point to the version found in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE then try the data export it still reports the mismatch.

So The Questions:
1 - Where do I download mysqldump.exe newer version?
2 - Or what is the solution?

I also found an app on the Win 10 machine that shows me all the MySQL stuff and allows me to Add or Update... and it reports that everything is up to date...

3 - But now I can't find out how to re-launch that tool... any ideas how to relaunch this app?

Answer (score 59):

I use MySQL Community Edition and I solved this problem today.

1. goto https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
2. download the ZIP archive of your desired version
3. Open the ZIP archive and go to "bin" folder
4. extract MYSQLDUMP.EXE where you want
5. Close the Zip Archive and open MySQl Workbench
6. In MySql Workbench goto to Edit > Preferences > Administration
7. Select the file that you just extracted in "Path to mysqldumptool"
8. Press OK and it's done!

31/01/2019 update: I need a Workbench or mysqldump.exe that works with a MySql server 5.7.18 CE. I can't find anything. Who can help me?

Comment: This gave me this error when I tried to use "Export Data": "Workbench was unable to get mysqldump version
". And idea?

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: good for me. try extract the whole zip files and specify the mysqldump.exe path to the workbench

Answer (score 5):

To download the *mysqldump.exe* version needed by *MySQL Workbench* to execute a dump, you have to download the *MySQL Community Server* from:

- if you need the latest GA version: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
- if you need previous GA versions: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ then click on *"Looking for previous GA versions?"*
- if you need an oldest archived version: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

After you have the archive, you can find *mysqldump.exe* inside "/bin" folder.

This is a standalone software so you can copy it where you want, then delete the rest of the archive.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you get 5.7 not 8.0 version of the zip file and extract all of the zip.

Answer (score 1):

Dont worry about different versions. Go to edit-Preference-administration- (careful here. go to mysql dump.exe that is found in xampp folder not mysql folder.) example of path should be like C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe. copy the path and paste in .path to mysqldump Tool.

Answer (score 0):

After installing mysql 5.7 it comes with all the dumptools and stuff so visit
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\
from
Edit > Preferences > Administration > path to dump tool 
and select your sql dump tool

note: same apply for any version of sql just navigate and get the dump tool for that version.